# Роутер DLink Dir - 100, после отключения из розетки слетело ПО

Tags: сеть, роутер

В MiniWeb не заходит, горит только индикатор питания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, только подключение через serial порт поможет узнать что с ним. Распиновка порта есть тут: http://hwmayer.blogspot.com/2010/09/d-link-dir-100-uart.htmlТолько там уровни 3,3в, так что нужен специальный конвертер с USB на 3,3в TTL.

Comment: Ну мне и так понятно, что с ним, такое уже было, но тогда получилось его "оживить" через Mini Web а сейчас комп его вообще не видит, походу проще новый купить (800 рублей всего). А если его к генератору постоянного тока подключить и выставить там 3,3v?

Comment: если его к генератору постоянного тока подключить и выставить там 3,3v, то ничего не будет, хотя, смотря куда подключить :) Если гарантия есть, и лень разбираться что с ним, то рекомендую его по гарантии отнести.

Comment: А если наклейка оторвалась? XD

Answer (score 0):

Это перепост с кокого-то форума. У меня после неудачных манипуляций с настройкой роута, он воообще умер. Так вот следующий маневр помог на 100% !!!!!

У тебя сейчас на нём нет прошивки вообще, поэтому1) в настройках сетевого подключения ставишь свой IP 192.168.0.2, основной шлюз 255.255.255.0, основным шлюзом пишешь IP роутера 192.168.0.1, DNS  - опять IP роутрера2) берёшь витую пару, вставляешь её в свою сетевуху, второй конец в WAN порт роутера3) зажимаешь Reset, включаешь роутер, держишь 5 сек и отпускаешь4) в браузере пишешь 192.168.0.1, откроется мини WEB, через эту менюху можно заново перепрошить

в общем то все просто!выключаешь апарат полностью! в wan-порт подключаешь комп. В компе настраиваешь сетевую следующим образом -ip-адрес: 192.168.0.2маска подсети: 255.255.255.0адрес шлюза: 192.168.0.1DNS1: 192.168.0.1DNS2: оставить пустым!эти настройки обязательны, иначе будут проблемы!после этого спичкой или ручкой или чем-нибудь тонким зажимаешь ресет на устройстве и держишь его 5 секунд. Не отпуская ресет включаешь в устройство питание и держишь при этом ресет! включив питание держишь еще 10 секунд ресет!!! потом отпускаешь, устройство включается! через ближайший тебе по душе интернет браузер заходишь на мини-веб роутера по адресу http://192.168.0.1/откроется до ужаса простая страница, на которой кнопкой обзор выбери файл с прошивкой и нажми upload, загрузить тоесть! через ~2 секунды оНо загрузится, нажми back - назад, типа)))потом нажми в самом низу - fla - типа прошить!жди около 30-40 секунд, если страница откроется - нажми опять back и потом сверху rebootесли не откроется в браузере нажми кнопку назад, на предыдущую страницу, типа, и нажми rebootdir-100 перезагрузится! после чего начнет благополучно работать! если вдруг не получится - повтори всю процедуру сначала! если не получится несколько раз - попробуй другую прошивку( другую версию), возможно, что некоторые версии будут работать не на всех устройствах!!! на ftp://-ресурсе длинка много бета версий которые не стабильны! старайтесь использовать НЕ бета версии!по всем вопросам вам поможет так же и форум http://forum.dlink.ru/

Comment: А теперь внимательно прочитайте мой вопрос